# How to express allowed values in a URI template

Tags: json, api, rest, hateoas

I'm working on a REST API, and I'm looking for a way to give the client allowed values for a variable in a URI template. This is useful when the variable represents something like an enum. Currently the client gets back a collection of links as part of the JSON object that is returned to it, and I'd like to do something like this:

```
"Links":
[
    {
        "Title":"Search Articles",
        "HREF":"example.com/articles/search?keywords={keywords}&mode={mode|["allWords", "anyWords", "exactPhrase"]}"
    }
]
```

or this:

```
"Links":
[
    {
        "Title":"Search Articles",
        "HREF":"example.com/articles/search?keywords={keywords}&mode={mode}"
        "Fields":
        [
            {
                "Name":"keywords",
                "Type":"Text"
            },
            {
                "Name":"mode", 
                "Type":"Enum", 
                "Options":["allWords", "anyWords", "exactPhrase"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/api-craft/2soXPzQMP5I) is the closest thing I've found to an answer, but I was hoping for something a bit more official.

I've also been looking at [the IETF standards doc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) for URI Templates, which seems pretty official, but doesn't look like it has an answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm going to go with [JSON Hyper-Schema.](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html) As suggested by [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20767057/2291670) you can accomplish what I'm after by using the Properties element they define.

I also looked at [HAL,](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)  [Collection+JSON,](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/)  and [Siren,](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren) but I prefer the JSON Hyper-Schema since it sticks with a collection of links, rather than coming up with something new.